# PHP File upload and overwrite file with same name

Tags: php, file-upload

I am making an application that allows users to upload a file in a directory via PHP.

I am having problems because it dose not allow me to overwrite files with the same name.
Eg I have a file called text.php and I upload it, now when I go back and change the content of file text.php and I upload it again on the server I still have the version without the edits. However if I upload another file it works. So I just can't overwrite files.

```
if ($_POST["greg"]=='true'){
// Set local PHP vars from the POST vars sent from our form using the array
// of data that the $_FILES global variable contains for this uploaded file
$fileName = $_FILES["file1"]["name"]; // The file name
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
$fileType = $_FILES["file1"]["type"]; // The type of file it is
$fileSize = $_FILES["file1"]["size"]; // File size in bytes
$fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["file1"]["error"]; // 0 for false... and 1 for true

// Specific Error Handling if you need to run error checking
if (!$fileTmpLoc) { // if file not chosen
    echo "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.";
    exit();
} else if($fileSize > 90000000000000) { // if file is larger than we want to allow
    echo "ERROR: Your file was larger than 50kb in file size.";
    unlink($fileTmpLoc);
    exit();
} else if (!preg_match("/.(doc|docx|xls)$/i", $fileName) ) {
     // This condition is only if you wish to allow uploading of specific file types    
     echo "ERROR: Your file is not the right format contact the master of the page for clarification.";
     unlink($fileTmpLoc);
     exit();
}
// Place it into your "uploads" folder mow using the move_uploaded_file() function
move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "documenti/$fileName");
// Check to make sure the uploaded file is in place where you want it
if (!file_exists("documenti/$fileName")) {
    echo "ERROR: File not uploaded<br /><br />";
    echo "Check folder permissions on the target uploads folder is 0755 or looser.<br /><br />";
    echo "Check that your php.ini settings are set to allow over 2 MB files, they are 2MB by default.";
    exit();
}
// Display things to the page so you can see what is happening for testing purposes
echo "The file named <strong>$fileName</strong> uploaded successfuly.<br /><br />";
echo "It is <strong>$fileSize</strong> bytes in size.<br /><br />";
echo "It is a <strong>$fileType</strong> type of file.<br /><br />";
echo "The Error Message output for this upload is: <br />$fileErrorMsg";

}
```

How can I change this code so that when I upload a file with the same name it overwrites the existing file?

Comment: Are you sure it doesnt get overwritten, with your code the standard behaviour on a LAMP-like server is that the file will be overwritten. SO make sure your CHMOD is 777

Comment: No, just go to your files with FTP and right click and set filerights to the maximum (Which is 777)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try  this (put it before upload a file)

```
//checking if file exsists
if(file_exists("documenti/$fileName")) unlink("documenti/$fileName");

//Place it into your "uploads" folder mow using the move_uploaded_file() function
move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "documenti/$fileName");
```

Comment: sry but dose not work , and i don't know how to set up permission 777

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the script does not have the rights to overwrite? Try to change the dir to 777 and test again. If it works then, you can figure out the correct value you need

Comment: i do that in the php.ini file

Answer (score 2):

```
if (file_exists("documenti/$fileName"))
 { 
 unlink("documenti/$fileName");

 echo "<font face='Verdana' size='2' >Last Uploaded File has been removed from uploads folder<br>back to uploadform agian and upload your file<br>";// now your file which uploaded before was deleted from uploads folder you can open it and check if it removed or not , so no you should go back to uploadform again and import your file which will uploaded correctly 

echo "<font face='Verdana' size='2' ><BR><BR><BR><a href='upform.php'>Back to upform</a><BR>";

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking if the file exists and deleting it if it does before you move the temporary file to the permanent storage location?

Comment: This needs to be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: no iam a self thought php noob so i am not sure how to do that but iam gonna look into it , thanks for advice

Comment: This should not be posted as an answer. Agree with @Bojangles.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $filePathAndName =  "documenti/$fileName";
   //check file exists
   if(file_exists($filePathAndName)) 
   {
      unlink($filePathAndName);
   }

    //move_uploaded_file() function
    move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, $filePathAndName);
```