# How can I overwrite a file, when the file I want to upload already exists?

Tags: php

I want to overwrite a file, if it already exists in the folder. Here is my code:

index.php

```
<form action="check.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <button type="submit" value="upload">Upload</button>
</form>
```

check.php

```
if(isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['file'];
    $target_file = 'files/'.basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "File already exist";                  
        echo "<form action='overwrite.php' method='post'>
                <button type='submit'> Overwrite</button>
            </form>";
    } 
}
```

overwrite.php

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
echo "The file is overwritten";
```

---

**Update:** I did a mistake in my question. Now I changed it. On check.php there should only be the statement "File already exists" and a button which directs to the overwrite.php and overwrite the file. (No second input field)

Comment: In overwrite.php the global variable `$_FILES` is empty.

Comment: Check your script has permission to overwrite the file. Alternatively, create a unique string as the file name so you avoid this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP File upload and overwrite file with same name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064618/php-file-upload-and-overwrite-file-with-same-name)

Answer (score 1):

when you are creating the form again you need to specify `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

```
 echo "<form action='overwrite.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <input type='file' name='file'>
        <button type='submit'> Overwrite</button>
    </form>";
```

without `enctype="multipart/form-data"`it wont let you perform file upload operation

other than that name should not be a value it should be static so you can use it

Comment: Hi, I changed it, like you suggested, but it is still not working

Comment: change the name to  static `file` from `$target_file`

Comment: This wouldn't overwrite the file if the script doesn't have permission to do so.

Comment: I did. My change: `<input type='file' name='file' enctype='multipart/form-data'>`. But still not working

Comment: @jarla buddy you are doing it wrong, `enctype='multipart/form-data'` should be added to `form` tag and keep your input name as `<input type='file' name='file'>` simply. see my answer i havent posted something like this

Comment: Sorry I found out I did an important mistake in my question. Please see the change in my question

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing `$_FILES["file"]` but, unless `$target_file==="file"`, you're not finding anything.

Change the `name` attribute of the file upload from `$target_file` to just `file`:

```
        echo "<form action='overwrite.php' method='post'>
                <input type='file' name='file'>
                <button type='submit'> Overwrite</button>
            </form>";
```

Comment: What do you see when you use `var_dump($_FILES)`?

Comment: Sorry, I did a mistake in my question. On check.php there shouldn't be a new input field, just a button to say overwrite. So on my check.php should only be the statement "File already exists" and a button which directs to the overwrite.php and overwrite the file.

Comment: Do you know how to get the code working without an input field on check.php?