# How can I replace an existing image in php

Tags: php, image, replace, upload

How can i REPLACE an existing image in a folder using php? 
When i click upload button, the images are just adding into my folder instead of replacing it. Can you please add or rearrange my code. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
} else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000000000) {
echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType 
!= 
"jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], 
$target_file)) {

    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has 
been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: how should it replace the file when you are checking if the file already exists? `if (file_exists($target_file)) {
echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP File upload and overwrite file with same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064618/php-file-upload-and-overwrite-file-with-same-name)

Answer (score 1):

Currently your code is ok, its just adding image to your folder and name of image is same as your file name.

As I have checked in your code, you have added condition for existing file which means if same name file you upload then its send you an error.

So just comment below code and try to run.

```
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
```

Comment: That code is not required, that is one type of validation

Comment: Okay thank you, but the image are still not replacing the old image, what code could I add sir? sorry for these questions, I'm a beginner : <

Comment: If file name for second files same then it will replace automatically

Answer (score 0):

Just comment or remove this piece of code:

from

```
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
```

to

```
// Check if file already exists
// if (file_exists($target_file)) {
// echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
// $uploadOk = 0;
// }
```

or delete it from your code...